# Deep lookup in the list of dicts

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a task that returns me a list of following dictionaries:

```
[
  {
    "state": available
    "id": "obj-1"
    "tags": {
      "Name": "pub-obj-1"
    }
  },
  {
    "state": available
    "id": "obj-2"
    "tags": {
      "Name": "pub-obj-2"
    }
  },
  {
    "state": available
    "id": "obj-3"
    "tags": {
      "Name": "pvt-obj-3"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to perform a lookup based on tags, with the prefix `pub` in the name and return the `id` fields of those objects in a new list. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Fix the [JSON](https://jsonlint.com/). The commas are missing in the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with an `if` clause to filter sub-dicts based on tag names.

Given your input list as `lst`:

```
[d['id'] for d in lst if d['tags']['Name'].startswith('pub-')]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/RingedUnpleasantDemand

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Lookup `tags` with the prefix `pub` in the `Name` and return the `id`."***

A: The filter [*json_query*](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#starts-with) does the job

```yaml
pub: "{{ out|json_query('[?tags.Name|starts_with(@, `pub`)].id') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
pub:
  - obj-1
  - obj-2
```

You can also use the filter *selectattr* and [*match*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) the prefix

```yaml
pub: "{{ out|selectattr('tags.Name', 'match', 'pub')|
             map(attribute='id')|list }}"
```

---

**Notes**

1. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    out:
      - id: obj-1
        state: available
        tags:
          Name: pub-obj-1
      - id: obj-2
        state: available
        tags:
          Name: pub-obj-2
      - id: obj-3
        state: available
        tags:
          Name: pvt-obj-3

    pub: "{{ out|json_query('[?tags.Name|starts_with(@, `pub`)].id') }}"
    pu2: "{{ out|selectattr('tags.Name', 'match', 'pub')|
                 map(attribute='id')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: pub
    - debug:
        var: pu2
```

2. Fix the JSON

```yaml
    [
        {
            "id": "obj-1",
            "state": "available",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "pub-obj-1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "obj-2",
            "state": "available",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "pub-obj-2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "obj-3",
            "state": "available",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "pvt-obj-3"
            }
        }
    ]
```